# Windows Forms Unhandled Exception Crash

Tags: c#, winforms, crash, appdomain, unhandled-exception

I have code that caters for my winforms application to handle an an unhandled exception. My application however still crash.

I do, at this stage, have no understanding why this behavior is. I would appreciate your assistance.

Here is my code:

```
 [STAThread]
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        bool result;
        var mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "MyApplication", out result);
        if (!result)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Another instance is already running.");
            return;
        }
        Application.ThreadException += ApplicationThreadException;
        Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainUnhandledException;
        Memory.frmMain = new MainForm();
        Application.Run(new MyApplicationContext());
        GC.KeepAlive(mutex);
    }
    public static void CurrentDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(((Exception)e.ExceptionObject).Message);
        ((Exception)e.ExceptionObject).AddLog();
        Memory.processtranslations.IsProcessing.Enabled = true;
    }
    public static void ApplicationThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message);
        e.Exception.AddLog();
        Memory.processtranslations.IsProcessing.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: What is `e.IsTerminating` in `CurrentDomainUnhandledException`? Saying *my application however still crashes*, do you mean that the MessageBox is not shown or that whatever `Memory` is doing also crashes? -- What is `e.Exception.AddLog()`? Do you have another Layer (logging Framework) there that's pre-handling Exceptions? -- I won't talk about how you're handling the `Mutex` there :)

Comment: I couldn't get this part `Memory.frmMain = new MainForm();` Could you share also other classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]` attribute to your Main method. What's more, get your main loop into try..catch:

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 //other code
  
  try
  {
    Application.Run(new MyApplicationContext());
  }catch(Exception)
  {
    //...
  }
}
```